# Perl6: run command as a different user

Tags: io, root, raku

How can Perl6 run commands as a different user?

**Context**: [zef module manager](https://github.com/ugexe/zef) is installed as a regular user and there some commands that need to be run as root.

**Temporary solution**: the following function allows running shell commands as a different user:

```
unit module Repo::Utils::RunAsUser; 
sub RunAsUser( Str $user, Str $command, --> Proc ) is export {
  return shell "su -c \'$command\' $user";
}
```

**Questions:**

- Is there an alternative syntax for running commands as root from a Perl6 script?
- Can a user run certain IO::Path methods and subroutines (like unlink or mkdir) as root?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there are any. Either you use the shell, or you use Native calls to Posix functions that do pretty much the same. I don't know if such a thing has been published, though. I just found this: https://modules.perl6.org/dist/IO::Path::Mode:cpan:JSTOWE which might be useful for this kind of thing.

Comment: Lets assume there was such a function as `run-as-root` -- now anyone could publish a module to do anything as root on anyone's system that installs said module. This ignores the fact `run-as-root` would also need a way to work on e.g. Windows.

Comment: @ugexe: you are right! At the same time, lets assume module A needs to be run as root, and module A uses modules B, C and D. To run module A, zef has to be installed as root and all other modules will run as root. Having a run-as-root function (like the example) ensures that only certain code will run as root.

Comment: @ugexe: AppleScript had a handy *with administrator privileges* clause that could be tagged onto shell commands: `do shell script 'rm important-file.foo' with administrator privileges` which would be analogous to, say `shell 'rm important-file.foo' :elevated` (to be generic for *nix *root* and Windows *Administrator*).  In AS, each run of the script would trigger an administrator PW prompt, and a bad password would cause the script to fail.  That might not be a terrible model to copy (either for a built in or for a module) in P6 and it would at least require user intervention for modules.

Comment: Ideally there would be no shelling out period. Especially for removing / modifying directories. And since most other things that use a shell also have an alternative that doesn’t (like prove vs TAP.pm6) I don’t see how that could work in a robust way.

Comment: @ugexe For sure, I was focusing just on the shell part and used *rm* as a quick example.  For files, though, because of the way sandboxing variably works across different OSes a general solution might be trickier (at least on the Mac, it's occasionally caused weird file access denials for me even in Apple-supplied programs for things in. my. home. folder), as there would need to be a way to both fail on denied access (easy enough) and also request access, which may require a system GUI prompt.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not 100% Perl6 solution but you can use Sparrow6 which is written in Perl6 to run commands under a user.

Examples:

https://github.com/melezhik/Sparrow6/blob/master/documentation/dsl.md#zef-modules

https://github.com/melezhik/Sparrow6/blob/master/documentation/dsl.md#bash-commands